# ruby sass, unable to resolve dependancies

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I downloaded two gem files: `Sass-3.3.7.gem` & `compass-0.12.6.gem`

I ran `gem install --local Sass-3.3.7.gem` which it installed.

Followed by the same command for `compass`, but got the error:

```
 unable to resolve dependencies: compass requires sass (~>3.2.19)
```

I'm installing them pre-downloaded as I have no connection. Anyone knows what can be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compass 0.12.6 apparently depends on sass ~>3.2.19, which means that the version of sass should be bigger than 3.2 and smaller than 3.3, so basically compass needs sass 3.2.x. You have two options.

1. Also download sass 3.2.19, install both versions of sass, use the latest one yourself and make compass happy.
2. Just install sass 3.2.19 and use that yourself as well, this obviously only works if you don't need any features introduced in sass 3.3.

Comment: There is a 3rd option:  Upgrade Compass to a version that is compatible with Sass 3.3.  Compass 1.0 is the earliest version that does so (you may need to run `gem install compass --pre` to get it if it hasn't already been released).

Answer (score 1):

Install Sass 3.2.19:

```
sudo gem install sass -v 3.2.19
```

I didn't need Sass 3.3.7, and Jekyll keep finding the latest version installed, so I got uninstalled Sass 3.3.7:

```
sudo gem uninstall sass
```

Sass doesn't seem to overwrite previous versions, so I still had 3.3.2 installed (if there are multiple versions installed it gives you a choice of what version you'd like to uninstall), so I uninstalled that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `gem dependency <gem name>` to see list of the gem dependencies and required versions.